# make javascript function form specific

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have some jquery/javascript code that alters some things on document ready and when a form input is changed. How do i make this form specific?

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name="item_price[]"]').live('change', function () {
        var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
        CalculateData(tr);
    });
```

If my form's id tag is "my_form", how do i make this little snippet occur only if item_price[] in the "my_form" is being changed and not all instances of the item_price[] input?

Comment: Have a look at the [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/). The [tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) might be helpful as well.

Comment: lol fastest gun in the west again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the selector code like  this `$('#my_form input[name="item_price[]"]')` instead

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the id selector, `#my_form`, to your existing selector:

```
$('#my_form input[name="item_price[]"]').live('change', function () {
    var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
    CalculateData(tr);
});
```

**Additional Information:**

jQuery selector reference: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1):

add `#my_form` to the jquery selector

```
$('#my_form input[name="item_price[]"]').live('change', function () {
    var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
    CalculateData(tr);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegate in the following way to attach the event handler to the form element. This has the added advantage of jQuery not having to process unrelated events (i.e. ones that originated from outside of the form).

```
$('form#my_form').delegate('input[name="item_price[]"]', 'click', function() {
    ...
});
```